# Comparing two dataframes to make a new one in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to PySpark and thus the question.

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` with columns `A, B and C`.
Only Col C can have different values in these two dataframes.
How do I compare the `df1` and `df2` and create df3 with columns `A, B C` which only has rows where the value of `C` is different between `A` and `B`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So, you would like to create a new dataframe which contains columns A and B (which equal in df1 and df2) then calculate the difference between columns A and B in column C?

Comment: @BillyJo_rambler No my df3 should only have rows where the value of C is different between df1 and df2. Does that explain?

Comment: @BillyJo_rambler I've updated the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Inner join and filter

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), ["a", "b"]).where(col("df1.c") != col("df2.c"))
```

If you want to handle missing values as well

```
df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), ["a", "b"], "fullouter").where(
    ~col("df1.c").eqNullSafe(col("df2.c"))
)
```